# Windows Phone Dev C#: Sending Information between Pages

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, windows-phone-7

I am trying to send several strings between two pages. However, the receiving page only interprets it as one. Any advice on how I can fix this.

Page 1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string urlofdestinationpage = "/Page1.xaml";
            urlofdestinationpage += string.Format("?SelectedIndex=" + playersList.SelectedIndex);
            urlofdestinationpage += string.Format("?Player1=" + textBox1.Text);
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(urlofdestinationpage, UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Page 2

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> x = this.NavigationContext.QueryString;
            String size = Convert.ToString(x["SelectedIndex"]);
            MessageBox.Show(size);
String player = Convert.ToString(x["Player1"]);
                MessageBox.Show(player1);
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
```

The receiving page outputs a message saying "0?Player1=" and does not recognize player1 as a value.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Your URI is malformed. The `?` indicates the beginning of the parameters, and each parameter must be separated by `&`.

The URI you're constructing is:

> Page1.xaml?SelectedIndex=0?Player1=...

The URI you should construct is:

> Page1.xaml?SelectedIndex=0&Player1=...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string urlofdestinationpage = "/Page1.xaml";
    urlofdestinationpage += string.Format("?SelectedIndex=" + playersList.SelectedIndex);
    urlofdestinationpage += string.Format("&Player1=" + textBox1.Text);
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(urlofdestinationpage, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apped the second and any additional parameter with & not ? just like in an URL: /Page1.xml?param1=x&param2=y